# fixed layer scrolling

Tags: css, scroll, css-float, css-position

HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
<div id="header">
<div class="logo"></div>
<div class="category"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrap { 
width:960px; 
margin:0 auto; 
position:relative; }


#header_wrap { 
position:fixed; 
top:0; 
left:0; 
width:100%; 
min-width:960px; 
height:105px; 
background:rgba(256, 256, 256, 0.6); z-index:999; }


#header {  
width:860px; 
position:relative;  
height:90px; 
padding:15px 40px 0 40px; 
margin:0 auto;  }

.logo { 
float:left; 
margin-top:-35px; }

.category { float:right; margin-top:-9px; }
```

I made a fixed header menu on top of page.
But if browser window's width is smaller than wrap width (especially, when zooming on safari in iphone/ipad.), I can't see the right side(category) of header(fixed).
Help!

Answer (score 2):

Do not specify the width in `'px'` give it in the form of `%`, as you maximize or minimize your browser then either the scrollbar will appear and cut off your div